# DHTMLX Scheduler Example

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I am interesting in use DHTMLX Scheduler, but I have a doubt with the graphic rendering of this scheduler. Someone can give me some example of use of this library with an endearing interface?

Answer (score -1):

It is a good tool and you can find many examples in their [website demos](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/samples/index.html). You can also check the provided [skins](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/skins.html). Lastly, you can have a look at the [views](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/views.html) you can use.

I would recommed you to have a look at those demos:

- http://roombooking.scheduler-net.com/
- https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/sample_basic.shtml

Also, my favorite view is the Timeline and you can find a good demo [here](https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/sample_timeline.shtml).

Finally, if you want to check how it looks in a production application, you can check some Case Studies [here](http://scheduler-net.com/docs/case-studies.html).